# Android Studio(Error inflating class fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, genymotion

I followed some tutorial of implementing android studio Material design for Navigation Drawer, then I installed genymotion to test my app for other API.
I Tested my app on API 16.
Then I got this error.

```
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.directioner.newjd/com.example.directioner.newjd.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.directioner.newjd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5606)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1809)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1721)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.directioner.newjd.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:58)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:920)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2159)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.directioner.newjd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            tools:context="com.example.directioner.newjd.MainActivity">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                layout="@layout/app_bar" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
                 android:textSize="35dp"
                android:text="MAP HERE" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.directioner.newjd.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_dr"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer">

</fragment>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My MainActivity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);



        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

And for my NavigationDrawerFragment.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {


    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private View containerView;
    private VivzAdapter adapter;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        adapter=new VivzAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On Click "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(position==1){
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),SubActivity.class));

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On Long Click "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }));
        return layout;
    }


    public static List<Information> getData() {
        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_home,R.drawable.ic_search_black,R.drawable.ic_favorite, R.drawable.ic_route, R.drawable.ic_place, R.drawable.ic_settings};
        String[] titles = {"Home","Search Location","Favorites", "Route", "Recent Location","Settings"};
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++) {
            Information current = new Information();
            current.iconId=icons[i];
            current.title=titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    savedToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void savedToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();

    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
    }


    class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;
        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener){
                Log.d("CHARLES: ","Constructor");
            this.clickListener=clickListener;
            gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    Log.d("CHARLES: ","onSingleTap"+e);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    //super.onLongPress(e);
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if(child!=null && clickListener!=null){
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child,recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                    Log.d("CHARLES: ","onLongPress"+e);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if(child!=null && clickListener!=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                    clickListener.onClick(child,rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            Log.d("CHARLES: ","OnInterceptTouchEvent"+gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)+" "+e);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("CHARLES: ","OnTouchEvent");
        }
    }

    public static interface ClickListener{
        public void onClick(View view,int position);
        public void onLongClick(View view,int position);
    }
}
```

My Fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.directioner.newjd.NavigationDrawerFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00BCD4"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_margin_top"
            android:background="#00BCD4"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="Charles Ivan Galvez"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank You!

Comment: Can you post the layout for fragment_navigation_drawer.xml? It appears that the issue may be in that file.

Comment: done adding fragment_navigation_drawer. Thanks.

Comment: what do you have set for @dimen/drawer_margin_top?

Comment: <dimen name="drawer_margin_top">48dp</dimen>
this.

Comment: Okay, is it defined only for a specific API? i.e. Is it defined in values-v21/dimens.xml?

Comment: You did it! Thank you! I didn't put drawer_margin_top on pre-lollipop devices. thank you. And after your fixed im facing a new error. I'll post it tomorrow. I need some sleep. thank you. such a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

In the exception, the line below implies there is a conversion problem:

```
10-15 16:12:15.295 1411-1411/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
```

Your fragment layout width has `android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_dr"` so I would suggest checking what value you have defined in `nav_dr`.

Comment: This is my nav_dr <dimen name="nav_dr">280dp</dimen>.
Instead of android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_dr" i changed it to android:layout_width="280dp" but still the same

Comment: @CharlesGalvez, start debugging simpler by using `wrap_content` or `match_parent` before using a fixed value. Also if you're supporting multiple resolutions, make sure `nav_dr` or any other named variable is not missing from the base dimes.xml or values.xml, whichever you are using.

Also make sure that any Material Design themes you are targeting have alternate themes that work on API 16.

Comment: Thank you. Both your answers are correct. thank you guys!

Comment: @CharlesGalvez, when you consider answers correct, accept them as answer. Also up-vote existing answers.